# How to return http 500 with soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am mocking my web service using soapUI.
Now, I also want to test fault. For this, the mock service (=soapUI) should return a HTTP 500.
Does anyone know, how soapUI can do this?

thanks

Comment: an easy way is by putting a syntax error in some critical application logic

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved with the following Groovy code:

```
mockRequest.getHttpResponse().sendError(500)
```

Answer (score 5):

Right Click on the MockResponse > Show MockResponse Editor Enter.
Look at MockResponse Properties on the left hand side, bottom
Scroll down to search for "Response HTTP-Status" edit the value to 500.

Answer (score 4):

- Create a mock service.
- Create a new mock response.
- Open the mock response editor (by double clicking it) and click on the exclamation mark symbol which creates a SOAP Fault response.

If you look at the RAW code of the answer, you see a 500 error code. (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error)

*Btw if you have created two reponses, a successful and a fault response, then when using the mock service service, SOAPUI alternates between the two responses.*